# Is it possible to upload a python http.server to heroku/any hosting service?

Tags: python, web, wsgi

So I've made a http.server with a main.py and everything

I would like to ask what are the next steps from here, as I have uploaded it to my (heroku) server

I tried to use gunicorn through

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

but app cannot be recognised.

My code is below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), Server)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

My other question is that if there a better way of doing this or is this the most efficient path?

Comment: So what exactly have you done so far? (Please show some code!) If you're using `http.server` and e.g. `serve_forever`, then you don't need a separate application server such as `gunicorn` (though your app may not be very performant).

Comment: I have updated my post with the code, so if I don't need `gunicorn` how should I approach this (sorry, I have not much experience with the web side of things!)

Comment: Right - with something like that, you'd want to make sure hostName is set to `"0"` and serverPort to (probably - see Heroku docs) 8000. Then in your procfile you'd just do `web: python main.py` and Heroku should route traffic to your app...